# Connect InputStream and OutputStream with PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I have two different scenarios where I am trying to connect an InputStream with OutputStream and both of the above scenarios are working as expected when the size of the data in the original InputStream is less than `BUFFER_SIZE`, however when it exceeds the `BUFFER_SIZE` it hangs and seem to be waiting to be consumed although the consumer of the final InputStream is trying to consume the stream.

Scenario 1:

```
PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(in);

service.decrypt(originalInputStream, os);
service.encrypt(is, finalOutputStream);
```

Here `decrypt()` method is consuming an `originalInputStream` and writing the output into the `PipedInputStream` (os) and I need to redirect the output into the next method `encrypt()` with the first argument and store the output of the `encrypt()` method into `finalOutputStream`.

Scenario 2:

```
public InputStream download(InputStream downloadableInputStream) {
   PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
   PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);

   service.encrypt(downloadableInputStream, os);

   return is;
}
```

Here the `download()` method accepts and returns InputStream where it will try to encrypt the stream using `encrypt()` method and the caller of the method will consume the encrypted stream.

Both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods internally create a new thread and uses countdown latch to wait for completion.

Both `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods are being used outside these scenarios without the PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream and they are working as expected with very large files, it only seem to be an issue while using PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream.

Comment: These piped streams are for use between threads, where one thread is reading while the other is writing. If you don't have a reading thread, the writing thread will block. Your use of them here is not valid. You need to just read your input and encrypt it to your output. No pipes necessary.

Comment: As I mentioned methods encrypt() and decrypt() creates a new thread so both PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream are being fed and consumed between threads.